# Set list as Response in Ajax

Tags: ajax, spring

when i try to send a list as a response from ajax calls, it goes to error part of the ajax function. But when i replace with string it going to success part of the ajax function. Plz help me... i am using spring framework and front end jsp...

ajax function:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function dateTxnsAjax(){
        var frmDate = $('#startdate').val();
        var toDate = $('#enddate').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "datePurPoints.do",
            data: "fromDate="+frmDate+"&toDate="+toDate,  
            success: function(response){
                alert('success...................');
            },
            error: function(xhr,e){
                alert('failed.....');
                 alert('Error while request: '+xhr.responseText);
                }
            });

    }
</script>
```

controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/datePurPoints.do", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public @ResponseBody List<MemberLookUp> datePurPoints(@RequestParam("fromDate")String fromDate,@RequestParam("toDate")String toDate,HttpSession session) {

List<MemberLookUp> invtLst1 = new ArrayList<MemberLookUp>();
        MemberLookUp membLkp = new MemberLookUp();
        membLkp.setOrganizationName("santosh");
        System.out.println(membLkp.getOrganizationName()+"karthick in chk");
        invtLst1.add(membLkp);
        System.out.println("karthick in final chk"+invtLst1.get(0).getOrganizationName());
        return invtLst1;
}
```

this is wat i am getting in alert:

Error while request: Apache Tomcat/6.0.18 - Error report

## HTTP Status 500 -

**type** Status report

**message**

**description** The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

#### Apache Tomcat/6.0.18

Comment: Is there any error printed in Java console or logs ?

Comment: Internal server error

Comment: There may be lots of cause for that error , but What is the stacktrace?

Comment: How 'll i get the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Returning a json array would help to resolve the above error.

```
JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(mybeanList);
System.out.println(jsonA);
```

Google Gson is the best library http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers ()

Comment: @KarthickGandhi please download external library from link provided and add this into your project. Showing you the error because the library is missing.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/detail?name=google-gson-2.2.3-release.zip&can=2&q=

Comment: @KarthickGandhi please accept this answer if it works for you.